# How can I validate function parameters in Perl?

Tags: function, perl, validation, function-parameter

Could you please tell me what in Perl is the smartest way to validate function parameter?

**Code-Snippet**:

```
sub testfunction {
    my ($args) = @_;
    my $value = $args->{value} || die "no value set";
    # process value ...
}


testfunction({value => 'Hallo'});

testfunction({novalue => 'Hallo'});
```

Is the above way an good alternative to validate function parameter in perl or are there smarter ways?
Many Thanks to everybody.

Comment: Related [What Perl modules are useful for validating subroutine arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433070/what-perl-modules-are-useful-for-validating-subroutine-arguments) and [Perl subroutine arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19234209/perl-subroutine-arguments).

Comment: See also [How to specify default values for optional subroutine arguments?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29577085/2173773) and [Perl: Named parameters validation best practice](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19514694/2173773)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It depends a lot on what you're trying to accomplish, and whether it's user input, local functions or remote functions.

I mean, some parameters - it's far easier to 'validate' by trying to use it. A file name for example - rather than trying to trap all the edge cases by hand, just pass it to `open .... or die $!`

And sometimes - it's more sensible to 'default-and-override'. E.g.:

```
my ( $first_thing, $second_thing ) = @_; 
$first_thing //= "default value";
$second_thing //= 0;
```

Note - use of `//` rather than `||` - it's *similar* in usage, but it tests for just being undefined - rather than being defined-but-false such as `''` or `0`.

And other times you want better still validation, by applying a set of validation regexes. Just be careful, some things - like email addresses or IP addresses - can be a lot more complicated to exhaustively validate than you think - so a simple edge case of 'was there a parameter at all' can work.

Of course, at that point you can also start looking at [function prototypes](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes). Which aren't anything like the prototyping you may think of from other languages:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

#says - must have a single scalar arg. 
sub testfunction($) {
   my ( $required_arg ) = @_; 
   print $required_arg;
}

testfunction(1);
testfunction;
```

The latter will fail with:

```
Not enough arguments for main::testfunction
```

Note - perl prototypes check *type* and *number* of arguments (e.g. is it scalar, is it array). But don't check values, and *can* have some slightly unexpected effects when it comes to passing in arrays.

I'd suggest that passing in hashes is quite well suited to a defaulting mechanism, because you can:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %defaults = (
  "test" => 1,
);

sub with_default {
    my %args = (%defaults, @_); 
    print Dumper \%args; 
}

with_default;
with_default(test => 4 );
```

But to go back to your original case - if your function simply won't work without 'value' being set, then it's good to spell it out in code:

```
if ( not defined $args -> {value} 
  or not $args -> {value} =~ m/^\w+$/ ) {
   die 'value parameter must be supplied and match m/^\w+$/';
}
```

It's probably worth mentioning 'taint' mode at this point. It's a feature of `perl` that you don't see in many other languages.

It specifically tells the interpreter that 'user supplied' is 'tainted' and thus *cannot* be used without validation. And that includes insecure paths, environment vars etc.

See [perlsec](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html#Taint-mode)

But:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl -T
use strict;
use warnings;

system "echo $ENV{'USERNAME'}";
```

Will fail - because `system` will not allow 'tainted' vars. (But `print` will). You need to pass it through a validation step (e.g. regex typically) before the 'taint' is removed.

Comment: Many Thanks to you. Great and very helpfull answer from you :)

Comment: You might want to use single quotes instead of doubles in your `die "value parameter ... match /^\w+$/"` as with double quotes,`$/` will be interpreted as a Perl variable.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with this:

```
$args->{value} || die "no value set";
```

Is that it would fail when value is defined but set to zero.

```
testfunction({value => 0});  #Oops!
```

That may be ok if zero is not allowed for the value.  But in general, a better design would be to use `exists` or `//` to check whether the hash key has been defined.

```
die "Value not defined!" if not exists $args->{value};

die "Value not defined!" unless exists $args->{value};

$args->{value} // die "Value not defined!";
```

For this simple statement I would tend to prefer `exists` because I think it reads a bit more clearly.  But `//` allows nice things like substituting default values, as shown in Sobrique's answer. I agree with Sobrique's more general advice about approaches, as well.

Comment: You can also use `//` in lieu of `||` which solves the problem you outline. (this requires a slightly newer version of Perl than I've seen installed in some places)